# Using recursion to display the same result in Binary Search and Insertion Sort (Python)

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search, insertion-sort

I want to add in recursion in Binary Search and Insertion Sort to have them displayed the same output but while compiling, could not troubleshoot it. Where could have gone wrong? Getting unexpected indent errors for both of them.

**Recursion using Binary Search**

```
def binarySearch(alist, item):
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(alist)//2
    if alist[midpoint]==item:
        return True
    else if:
        if item<alist[midpoint]:
            return binarySearch(alist[:midpoint],item)
    else:
            return binarySearch(alist[midpoint+1:],item)

testlist = [0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42,]
print(binarySearch(testlist, 3))
print(binarySearch(testlist, 13))
```

**Recursion using Insertion Sort (With a list)**

```
def insertionSort(list):

  if i >= len(list):
    return list
  if list[i-1] > list[i]: 
    temp = list[i]
    for a in range(0, i): 
      if temp < list[a]:
        list.insert(a,temp)
        del list[i+1]
        break
  return insertionSort(list, i+1)

        while position > 0 and list[position - 1] > currentvalue:
            list[position] = list[position - 1]
            position = position - 1

        list[position] = currentvalue

list = [0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42,]
insertionSort(list)
print(list)
```

Comment: unexpected? in your binary search i already see you have an `else if <condition>:` without condition and in the else statement right below you have an indent error

Answer (score 3):

> Code blocks are defined by their indentation. By "code block", I mean functions, if statements, for loops, while loops, and so forth. Indenting starts a block and unindenting ends it. There are no explicit braces, brackets, or keywords. This means that whitespace is significant, and must be consistent. In this example, the function code (including the doc string) is indented four spaces. It doesn't need to be four spaces, it just needs to be consistent. The first line that is not indented is outside the function.

by [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to know how to use indentation. in your binary search code there are multipe indentation errors and here is the fix:

```
def binarySearch(alist, item):
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(alist)//2
    if alist[midpoint]==item:
        return True
    else:
        if item<alist[midpoint]:
            return binarySearch(alist[:midpoint],item)
        else:
            return binarySearch(alist[midpoint+1:],item)

testlist = [0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42,]
print(binarySearch(testlist, 3))
print(binarySearch(testlist, 13))
```

but your insertion sort is another story. you have undefined variables and etc. here is another implementation of insertion sort:

```
def insertionSort(list,i):
    if i<=1:
        return
    insertionSort(list, i - 1)
    currentvalue = list[i - 1]
    position = i - 2

    while (position >= 0 and list[position] > currentvalue):
        list[position + 1] = list[position]
        position = position - 1
    list[position + 1] = currentvalue


list = [0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 11, 19, 9, 42,]
insertionSort(list,len(list))
print(list)
```